# WhatsApp WebHook is called by someone how do I return a response from the WebHook?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webhooks, whatsapp

I am fairly new to WhatsApp so this may be a very simple problem.

When my webhook gets called by a user with a quick reply, let's just say a "OK" message and I want to return a simple text message such as "Great". How is that done? Do I need to configure a ChatBot? Send a new text message?

The current controller, asp.net MVC 5

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Hook( Root data )
    {
        Entry entry = data.entry.First();
        Change change = entry.changes.First();
        List<Message> messages = change.value.messages;
        string body = messages.First().text.body;

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult( HttpStatusCode.OK );
    }
```

I would like to be able to return a real response, "Have a great day!", for example.

Suggestions and insight are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the string with the following code:

```
return Content("Great", "text/plain");
```

**Update**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Hook( Root data )
{
    try
    {
       Entry entry = data.entry.First();
       Change change = entry.changes.First();
       List<Message> messages = change.value.messages;
       string body = messages.First().text.body;

       return new HttpStatusCodeResult( HttpStatusCode.Ok);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Log Exception Error
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult( HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError );
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I have tried several variaitions of this, including returning json. I need to know if the whatapp api even supports returning anything other than a status.

Comment: Usually when sending a post request one does not need to return other then the status code that either indicates if the post request was successful or not. I have updated my answer. Could be like you mention, that whatsapp does not allow any content to be returned other then the status code for a post request.

Comment: It does to work, my temporary access token had expired. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it works sometimes, still trying to work out exactly when, but I do not plan on using it. I think returning the StatusCode is correct.